# Show select box only when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I use this code in order to show/hide select box depends if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('[type="checkbox"][name="fields[special_proj_checkbox_field][]"]').change(function(){
      $('select.select').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

This code is executed in the back-end, in the edit post screen.
It works well except for one thing -- the first time I get to the edit post screen, the checkbox isn't checked, but the select box is visible, only after I check the checkbox and unchecked it again, the box is hiding.

How can I make it hidden by default?

Comment: Can't you just add `display: none` or hide it in the beginning of the `document.ready` event callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can initially hide the select

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var select = $('select.select').hide();
   //or select = $('select.select').toggle();
    $('[type="checkbox"][name="fields[special_proj_checkbox_field][]"]').change(function(){
      select.toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I have another problem, after I check the checkbox and save the post, the select box become hide again.. @pgk

Comment: if you save checkbox value to database and if it is checked/unchecked when post is loaded, you can do initial check:
`var select = $('.select), chk = $('[type="checkbox"][name="fields[special_proj_checkbox_field][]"]');`

`if (chk.is(':checked') select.hide();`

`chk.change(function(){select.toggle(this.checked);}`

Comment: By the way you there is no need to select checkbox with `[type="checkbox"]`. It's supposed that the name must be unique, so it's enough to do select only by the name. Depends of course of current situation ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know jQuerys `.hide()` function is triggering `display:none`. So you may initially add `display:none` to your box or add a `$.hide()` at the very beginning of your code.